# Discord.js - Im wondering how to un-server mute my bot when it gets server muted

Tags: discord.js

Sort of like how the Groovy bot automatically self-defans, im wondering how to do the same thing but opposite and for muting. Basically when the bot detects it has been server muted, it will automatically un-server mute. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if(newState.id === client.user.id && newState.serverMute) newState.setMute(false); // unmute bot
});
```